# What is the difference between accessors and normal functions in javascript object?

Tags: javascript, function, accessor

What is the specific difference between these two functions (one is an accessor property getter) in a javascript object other than the manner in which they are called?

```
var o = {
  foo: function() { return "bar"; },
  get foo2() { return "bar2"; }
}
```

Comment: `get foo2() { return "bar2"; }` is not a valid js syntax.

Comment: @Uzbekjon http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5

Comment: you don't have to invoke getter functions, they act like properties, which means they also show up in JSON, but normal methods don't.

Comment: My bad, I haven't look at ES5 yet, but I guess it's time )  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: `o.foo` returns a function callback, `o.foo2` returns a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get), Sometimes it is desirable to allow access to a property that returns a dynamically computed value, or you may want to reflect the status of an internal variable without requiring the use of explicit method calls. In JavaScript, this can be accomplished with the use of a *getter*.

---

> A `method` is a `function` associated with an `object`, or, simply put, a method is a property of an object that is a function. Methods are defined the way `normal functions` are defined, except that they have to be assigned as the property of an object.

`foo2` acts more like a property than a method which will/can hold a dynamic value.

```js
var o = {
  foo: function() {
    return "bar";
  },
  get foo2() {
    return "bar2";
  }
};
//To invoke 'foo'
console.log(o.foo());
//To invoke 'foo2'
console.log(o.foo2);
```